# Artifactory: Automatically query latest build number REST

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I am using the REST API to find build info. I'm using the query below:

```
GET /api/build/{buildName}/{buildNumber}
```

If you do not include the build number it will return basic info for every recorded build run. If you include the build number you actually get detailed info about that build. How can I automatically use the latest build number?

Answer (score 0):

You can post to `/api/search/buildArtifacts` sample requestBody:

```
 {"buildName":"my_build_name", "buildNumber":"LATEST"}
```

This will return a list of artifacts full downloadUri's but you would need to then use their path/properties to get the actual build info.